# Wordpress C# User Login

Tags: c#, wordpress

I have a very basic C# login system first i've work with localhost and basic databasebase username-password but now i want to connect my project to my website which is wordpress then i realize wordpress database is not at all basic they encrypt user passwords.

This is the code of my login system

```
MySqlCommand cmd =
                    new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM member.member WHERE username=@username AND password=@password ;",
                        connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", this.metroTextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", this.metroTextBox2.Text);
```

and this is a example password which is 123456

$P$B84VsdpgngrtX/Aep0VNW3X1mz8mzJ.

But this is 123456 too

$P$B9sKzYbWqf.BTewOR7G.4j2.1.7S87/

and this

$P$BCkM0oYKnu2/M1Xz5BtDBjnLqKOn.4.

how can i recode my program and check password true or false.

Comment: The right way would be to use the Wordpress API directly: https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Users

Comment: @RonBeyer i don't know how to use API i'm new at these thing.

Comment: Luckily there are libraries for that kind of thing that make it easy, simple Google search of "wordpress api c#" gave this nice library: http://abrudtkuhl.github.io/WordPressSharp/

Comment: @RonBeyer i don't think i can do it thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*Long time ago asked, but answering for my future self:*

Found this link to a CryptSharp Library.
https://www.zer7.com/software/cryptsharp

Downloaded the file (.Net Framework 2.0) copied all files to a new .Net Core (3.1) project and compiled without touching any file.

Got the wordpress passwordcheck working without any problems!

[Original stackexchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175806/duplicate-hash-method-for-password-in-net)

[And this blogpost (in French)](https://istacee.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/implementation-c-de-phpass/)